# Using JavaScript to navigate a complex/bloated DOM structure

Tags: javascript, dom

I was given what should be a fairly simple and straightforward task at work, use JavaScript to disable or remove a button. This is easy as all I really need to do is button.disabled = true. However I havent been able to figure out a path in the DOM to access the button.

It is 3rd party software that was purchased around 2004. There is no point in asking the company to disable the button for us as its no longer really supported as its just a product they acquired when purchasing another company. The source code is php and has been encrypted so we cant read or modify it. Thankfully they did not do the same process to the JavaScript files and left the opening to disable the button. The page elements are not correctly identified as name and id attributes have not been consistently set.

What I have tried

- document.contains("Export_CSV")
- document.body.contains("Export_CSV")
- document.getElementById() - button is named, no id'ed
- document.getElementByName("Export_CSV") - gives Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByName'
- trying both the getelement methods on the parts of the path I have successfully navigated to has shown that it only works at the current level and no sub-levels as I thought it would. For some reason I am forced to navigate the elements manually instead of easier access routes.

The JavaScript file which I am working from is originally loaded into an iframe on the page. Working from there I have managed to navigate part of the way but it has been slow and frustrating. The following access path is what I have managed so far

> window.parent.window.frames[2].document.forms[0].document.getElementById("ReportTable").document.getElementById("ReportLayout")

The full path that is shown by the DOM Explorer is:

> Html/body/iframe#id=dataFrame/html/body/form/table#id=ReportTable/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td#id=ReportLayout/fieldset/table/tr/td/button#name=Export_CSV

Where I have included the name and id of elements as they have been set. At times I am forced to list elements so I can choose the correct one. Such examples are the document.forms[0] and window.frames[2] above. To find that information I used methods such as

> var table_count = target_loc.document.getElementsByTagName("table");
>
> alert("table: " + table_count.length);
>
> var i;
>
> for (i = 0; i < table_count.length; i++) {    alert(i + ": name: " + table_count[i].name + "  id: " + table_count[i].id); }
>
> table names under window.parent.window.frames[2].document.forms[0]

So the last part of the path I need to navigate through is

> fieldset/table/tr/td/button#name=Export_CSV

But I haven't managed to figure out how to navigate inside the fieldset. I will also likely need help accessing and navigating the unnamed or id'ed table. Once I am in the table I expect I can get the rest as I should be able to use document.getElementByName then, or simply navigate with row[] and stuff.

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName (spelled correctly)

Comment: @SLaks ' comment. Or alternatively, the all-purpose [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like this: `document.querySelector('[name="leName"]')`

Comment: @Watilin The querySelector was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. I want to mark this as an answer but its only a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanielWatt (OP) wanted me to post an actual answer, so here it comes. Today JavaScript has [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which enables to select an element based on a CSS selector.

```
document.querySelector('[name="leName"]')
```

One thing to mention though: when performance is important, it’s best to specify a tag name (e.g. `input[name="leName"]` or `form[name="leName"]`). An attribute selector alone is treated as “any tag”, just like `*`, and is one of the least efficient selectors. For further reading, see [CSS performance has changed for the better](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/).